# Solidity: How to type cast string memory to address and uint type?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, evm

I get the following errors when trying to type cast string memory to address and uint type.

`TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "string memory" to "address".`

`TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "string memory" to "uint256".`

Below is the solidity code.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Test {
    struct allowedTokenDetails {
        address admin;
        uint256 price;
        uint256 balance;
        address rewardToken;
        uint256 timestampAdded;
        uint256 timestampLastUpdated;
    }
    mapping(address => allowedTokenDetails) public allowedTokensData;
    
    function setAllowedTokensData(address _token, string[][] memory _data) public {
        for (uint256 dataIndex = 0; dataIndex < _data.length; dataIndex++) {
            string memory dataKey = _data[dataIndex][0];
            string memory dataValue = _data[dataIndex][1];
            if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(dataKey)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked("admin"))) allowedTokensData[_token].admin = address(dataValue);
            if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(dataKey)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked("price"))) allowedTokensData[_token].price = uint256(dataValue);
            if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(dataKey)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked("balance"))) allowedTokensData[_token].balance = uint256(dataValue);
            if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(dataKey)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked("rewardToken"))) allowedTokensData[_token].rewardToken = address(dataValue);
            allowedTokensData[_token].timestampLastUpdated = block.timestamp;
        }
   }
}
```

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of validating the input with a set of `if` statements and typecasting each value based on the function logic, you can already pass the input data in expected types in a prepared struct:

```
struct inputData {
    address admin;
    uint256 price;
    uint256 balance;
    address rewardToken;
}

function setAllowedTokensData(address _token, inputData[] memory _data) public {
    for (uint256 dataIndex = 0; dataIndex < _data.length; dataIndex++) {
        allowedTokensData[_token] = allowedTokenDetails(
            _data[dataIndex].admin,
            _data[dataIndex].price,
            _data[dataIndex].balance,
            _data[dataIndex].rewardToken,
            0, // `timestampAdded` not set in your snippet
            block.timestamp
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of this method but I don't want to initialize all variables in the struct, only selected ones.